# How do I copy a file from my desktop, to another directory not on my desktop?

Tags: command-line, terminal, cp

In my Desktop directory, I have a file called "ex12.txt"

I want to copy it and move it to another directory named "temp" in another location.

I've tried this:

Jahvons-MacBook-Air:desktop jahvonashmeade$ **cp ex12.txt temp/**

Then I get this

**cp: directory temp does not exist**

What exactly am i doing wrong?

EDIT: Never mind guys I found out the problem. I was skipping the root folder in the path directions.

Comment: where is your temp directory?

Answer (score 0):

copy/paste by chance. Seems fairly simple and easy to do

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programmatic answers; this seems like you're just telling the user to manually copy and paste?